# Nets - preoredered sets or posets?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, nets

**Question:** Usually net is defined as a function from a directed
preordered set to a topological space. What would we lose or gain
if we worked with partially ordered directed sets only?

---

**Background and motivation**

For me, one of the most important property of
[nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29) in
topological spaces is the following:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $x\in X$ and $A\subseteq x$.
> Then $x\in\overline A$ if and only if there exists a net
> $(x_d)_{d\in D}$ such that $x_d$ converges to $x$ and $x_d\in A$
> for each $d\in D$.

The above property means that topology of $X$ is uniquely
determined by convergence of nets.

The above property would be true also if we worked only with nets
on directed posets.

Indeed, let $x\in\overline A$. Let $\mathcal N_x$ be the set of all open
neighborhoods of $x$. Then $D=(\mathcal N_x,\supseteq)$ is a
poset, which is directed. For any $U$ choose one element $x_U\in
A\cap U$. Then the net $(x_U)_{U\in\mathcal N_x}$ converges to
$x$.

So, if I did not make a mistake in this proof, the above property
is true also if we work only with nets on posets.

---

In some constructions it is useful that we are allowed to work with nets on preordered sets. One of them is constructing a net corresponding to a given filter $\mathcal F$ such that this net converges to $x$ if and only if the filter $\mathcal F$ does. Here the net on the set $\{(A,a); a\in A\in \mathcal F\}$ preordered by $$(A,a)\le (B,b) \Leftrightarrow A\supseteq B$$ is used, and this is indeed a preordered set, not a partially ordered set. See the part on correspondence of nets and filters in [P. L. Clark's notes on convergence](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf) for more details and other related constructions. In fact, P. L. Clark writes here that this *"justifies our willingness to entertain directed quasi-ordered sets".* (This answers to some extent my question. But I guess that the authors working with posets also have some reasons to do so.)

---

Another possible viewpoint:

For any class $\mathcal C$ of directed sets we can define the
class of topological spaces defined by the property:

> $V$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $V$ is closed w.r.t. limits
> of nets on directed set from $\mathcal C$.

- If $\mathcal C$ = all directed sets, then we get all topological spaces.
- If $\mathcal C=\{\mathbb N\}$, then we get [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space.)
- If $\mathcal C=$ well-ordered sets or $\mathcal C=$ linearly ordered sets, then we get pseudoradial spaces

So in this context we can view this question as the question what we get if
$\mathcal C$=directed posets (which seems quite natural, after seeing that several classes of spaces arise in this way).

---

Going through literature and also quick google searches bellow shows that quite a few authors use posets and not preordered sets.

- [topology net preordered](https://www.google.com/search?q=topology+net+preordered&tbm=bks)
- [topology net preorder](https://www.google.com/search?q=topology+net+preorder&tbm=bks)
- [topology net poset](https://www.google.com/search?q=topology+net+poset&tbm=bks)
- [topology net "partially ordered"](https://www.google.com/search?q=topology+net+%22partially+ordered%22&tbm=bks)

I could mention a few books which use posets:

- Munkres: Topology, Supplementary Exercises after Chapter 3, p. 187 in 2nd edition. (Although he does not pay much attention to nets - they are left as supplementary exercises.)
- Runde: A taste of topology, see Definition 1.3.3 on [p.18](https://books.google.com/books?id=BUzOSed1sEEC&pg=PA18) and Definition 3.2.8
  on [p.73](https://books.google.com/books?id=BUzOSed1sEEC&pg=PA73)
- Bukovský: The Structure of the Real Line [p.32](https://books.google.com/books?id=qt5CoCEVxzAC&pg=PA32)

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72204/do-we-need-net-refinements-not-induced-by-preorder-morphisms)

Answer (score 9):

In Hausdorff spaces, we probably lose little either way.  In the "partial order" setting we require the axiom of choice more often.  (Did you see "choose" in your write-up?  Now do the same thing WITHOUT the axiom of choice...)

There is more than one paper where the author claims something doesn't work for nets (in order to justify his/her use of filters) by incorrectly requiring the partial-order version of directed set.

One use of nets (indeed, the *original* use by Moore and Smith) is to explain the convergence used in the definition of the Riemann integral, where you have a Riemann sum for each tagged partition of an interval, and you direct them by refinement, allowing any choice of tags.  Preordered only!

**added**
This came up again, so let me amplify my remark about non-Hausdorff spaces, and avoiding the axiom of choice (AC).

Let $(X, \mathscr X)$ and$(Y, \mathscr Y)$ be topological spaces, let $f : X \to Y$ be a function, let $a \in X$.  For $a \in X$ let
$\mathscr X_a = \{U \in \mathscr X : a \in U\}$ be the set of open
neighborhoods of $a$; similarly for $\mathscr Y_b$.  We say that
$f$ is continuous at $a$ iff:

> for every $V \in \mathscr Y_{f(a)}$
> there exists $U \in \mathscr X_a$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

But if we like to use nets, we want to say: this is equivalent to

> for every net $(p_d)_{d \in D}$ in $X$, if $p_d \to a$ then $f(p_d) \to f(a)$.

To avoid AC we do it like this:  Suppose $f : X \to Y$ is discontinuous at $a$.  We want to find a net with $p_d \to a$ but $f(p_d) \not\to f(a)$.
Easy:  Let
$$
D = \big\{(U,x) : x \in U, x \in U \in \mathscr X_a\big\}
\tag1$$
ordered by
$$
(U_1,x_1) \le (U_2, x_2) \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad U_1 \supseteq U_2.
\tag2$$
This is directed because: the intersection of two open sets is open.
[We avoided AC here; we did not choose an element of $U$, instead we use all of the elements.]

Define a net $(p_d)_{d \in D}$ by $p_{(U,x)} = x$.  Then we can show $x_d \to a$.  Indeed, given $U \in \mathscr X_a$, we have $p_d \in U$ for all
$d \ge (U,a)$.

Also we claim $f(p_d) \not\to f(a)$.  We assumed $f$ is discontinuous at $a$.  So there is $V$ with $f(a) \in V \in \mathscr Y_{f(a)}$ but for any $U \in \mathscr X_a$ we have
$f(U) \not\subseteq V$.  That is: there is $(U,y) \in D$ with
$f(p_{(U,y)}) \notin V$.

---

Remarks.  Notice that, in a non-Hausdorff space, it could be that
there is a minimal open set with more than one element.  The construction above still works.  But the directed set ($1$) ordered by ($2$) is not partially ordered.  Only quasi-ordered.

The originating material on nets (Birkhoff 1950, then Kelley 1955) used quasi-ordered directed sets, so everything worked.  Subsequent readers of their expositions have sometimes not noticed this.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that I was using AC, but thanks for pointing it out explicitly. I do not know, whether the same is possible in ZF - in fact I did not think about it; but if I'm working in ZFC this should not be much of a hindrance. (Topology without AC is quite weird anyway.)

Comment: @Martin: Quite is a big understatement... :-) (Trivial example: Separable space with a subspace which is not separable.)

Comment: So what would be an example of a cycle involving partitions with a Riemann integral?

Comment: @mike4ty4 ... One partition, but two different choices of tags.  Each is $\le$ the other in our ordering.  but we don't care that they are $\ne$.

Comment: Really like your answer @GEdgar.  Thinking about Riemann sums ... seems to me we could massage the structure of the tagged paritions of an interval back into a partially ordered directed set by defining < to mean strict refinement and = to mean "exactly the same" (including the tagging).  (i.e. two different taggings of the same partition will not be comparable.)  With these meanings, as I mentioned above, I think $\leq$ will give the collection of tagged partitions the structure of a partially ordered set with a direction.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That can be done in ZFC. Do you mean something specific with "space"? Like metric space?

Comment: @Jakobian: Yes. Metric space. Or, you know, $\Bbb R$.